# Syntax for parametrizing the switch statement

Tags: r

Consider the following example:

```r
x <- '3'
switch(x, '1' = 'Case 1', '2' = 'Case 2', '3' = 'Case 3')
```

I would like to parametrize the options, something along the lines of:

```r
cases <- list(
    '1' = 'Case 1',
    '2' = 'Case 2',
    '3' = 'Case 3'
)
switch(x, cases)
```

The `cases` object might not necessary be a `list`, but the idea is to dynamically pass a dictionary-like object to be used by `switch`.

This is probably trivial, but what is the correct syntax to achieve this?

Note: would prefer a base-R solution. There should be multiple ways to achieve this, would also look for the shortest and simplest solution.

Comment: `do.call('switch', c(x, cases))`